# Why do values from Data.Unique need to be hashed before being exposed?

Tags: haskell, unique, ghc, radix

`Data.Unique.hashUnique` is used to obtain an almost-unique `Int` from a `Unique` value:

```
hashUnique :: Unique -> Int
#if defined(__GLASGOW_HASKELL__)
hashUnique (Unique i) = I# (hashInteger i)
#else
hashUnique (Unique u) = fromInteger (u `mod` (toInteger (maxBound :: Int) + 1))
#endif
```

Why doesn't `Data.Unique` offer a function like `getUnique` for obtaining truly unique values?

```
getUnique :: Unique -> Integer
getUnique (Unique i) = i
```

Was this an oversight in the development of the library? Can we get such a function added to Data.Unique? There are many cases where *truly* unique values are needed.

Comment: Why do you need to obtain an `Int` or `Integer`. Why not simply use the `Unique` (which is truly unique) directly?

Comment: Because I need to print it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

`Data.Unique` values aren't truly unique. If you inspect the source, you'll see that the protected constructor simply increments a `TVar` with a counter and each unique value simply has the next counter value. So you'll get a `Unique 1` then a `Unique 2` etc. But you probably already knew that.

Because the integers are in increasing order, and the hash of an `Integer` simply is its integral value stored in an `Int`, you'll never get hash collisions up to the limit of an `Int` (On 64-bit machines, an `Int` can have 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 distinct values). So, you'll basically never ever get hash collisions.

An `Unique` value is guaranteed to be unique for a program session. That's all it is. It's not guaranteed to be printable or reusable across universes. If you need printable universally unique values, you should use [Universally Unique Identifiers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid).

Comment: I know the semantics of Unique and its purpose. My question is valid regardless. Why should the library limit me to `maxBound :: Int` unique values when it doesn't have to?

Comment: The only reason why `Unique`s have defined hash values is so that they can be hashed, and used as keys in `HashMap`s for example. Why does the `hashString` function return an `Int` and not an `Integer` with all the `String`s bytes? Because that's not the purpose of the `hashString` function; it should hash strings. The reason why there isn't a `uniqueToInteger` function **too** for `Unique`s is that the fact that it uses `Integer`s internally is an implementation detail. The library developer should be free to switch to `ByteString`s instead or something without breaking code.

Comment: There are cases where it is useful to have an unbounded number of unique values (think of a long-running server process, for example). The `Data.Unique` library has the potential to fill that role, but currently it does not. I am interested in adding this functionality to the library or a good reason against it.

Comment: Then make a `counter` library that has the purpose of generating an unbounded number of unique **integer values**. It's only about 10 lines of code anyways. It's not the purpose of `Data.Unique` to generate unique **integers**, only unique **values**.

Comment: Why should I pollute Hackage with another library when this functionality can be cleanly added to an existing library? Hackage is polluted enough as it is.

Comment: It can't be cleanly added. As I said, it would rob the library author one of his freedoms; he'd no longer be able to replace an implementation detail (e.g. if he wanted to switch to `ByteString` from `Integer`). If you don't want to add a Hackage library, then feel free to use a module internal to your project.